# Hosting package dist/assets in another package (Vite/VueJS)

Tags: vue.js, node-modules, vite, yarn-workspaces

I have one package which I build with Vite which is generating some assets in `package-A/dist/assets`. These assets are then referenced in some of the generated Javascript/HTML e.g. `href="assets/A.css"`. I then have another package (i.e. package-B) which depends on package-A. When I use `vite dev`, or `vite build` and `vite preview`, the assets from package-A are not included in package-B's dist folder and are not available at `localhost/assets/A.css`.

How can I get package-B to host the files inside package-A's dist/assets folder.